# Who can sign off the aircraft after completion of 100-Hour Inspection?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-maintenance

Can the mechanic who performed 100-hour inspection sign off the aircraft?

Comment: What do you mean by "sign off" the aircraft? And can we assume you're asking about the US (FAA) regulations?

Answer (score 3):

## Yes.

In the United States, annual inspections must be signed off by an IA, but 100-hour inspections may be signed off by the A&P that performed the inspection.

Comment: In general, that is what differentiates the 100 hour and Annual inspections. Otherwise they are the same.